# How to position divs in columns after exiting viewport?

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to position divs vertically 2 by 2 (first column has 2 divs, second has 2) and when I get to the end of the viewport instead of continuing to show the right (which will leave the page and have to use the horizontal scroll) I would like it to show below the main div to look like this:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

But what I got was this:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Here's the code:

page.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<h2> Start</h2>
<div class="page">
  <div class="vertical">
    <div class="container"><h3 class="text">1</h3></div>
    <div class="container"><h3 class="text">2</h3></div>
    <div class="container"><h3 class="text">3</h3></div>
    <div class="container"><h3 class="text">4</h3></div>
    <div class="container"><h3 class="text">5</h3></div>
    <div class="container"><h3 class="text">6</h3></div>
    <div class="container"><h3 class="text">7</h3></div>
    <div class="container"><h3 class="text">8</h3></div>
    <div class="container"><h3 class="text">9</h3></div>
    <div class="container"><h3 class="text">10</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

style.css:

```
.page {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 1500px;
}

.vertical{
    width: 100vw;
    height:100vh;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    background-color: gray;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.container{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: white;
}

.text {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
    font-size: 60px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you can try this approach in below snippet =>

```css
.page {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 1500px;
}

.vertical{
    width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    background-color: gray;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.text {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical">
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">1</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">2</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">3</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">4</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">5</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">6</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">7</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">8</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">9</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">10</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">11</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">12</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">13</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">14</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">15</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">16</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">17</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">18</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">19</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">20</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">10</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">11</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">12</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">13</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">14</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">15</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">16</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">17</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">18</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">19</h3></div>
  <div class="container"><h3 class="text">20</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helps, but it's not exactly the solution I'm looking for. What I want is for the content that overflows the viewport (overflow-x) to be shown in a new <div class="vertical"> that is below the previous one.